# Metadata loading was interrupted because of data fetching issues. For details, see the log

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, database-migration, aws-sct

I use AWS Schema Conversion Tool to migrate a data base source SQL Server to PostgreSQL, but the DB schema does not load and I get this error message " Metadata loading was interrupted because of data fetching issues. For details, see the log "

And on the log file I find this message: 
" Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to resolve the classification conflict between "French_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the operation equal to."

I tried to change the collation of my DB using "ALTER DATABASE 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS; " But it doesn't resolve the problem .

Can someone help me please ?